# Values Entered in a textbox or radio button list changes after firing an event clear when the event posts back?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, input, postback

In ASP.net I have a simple textbox and radio button list with yes or no options. On the VB server-side I implement OnClick of the radio button and it does things.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbltest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"      OnSelectedIndexChange="rbltest_SelectedIndexChanged"                                                                      <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="No" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The only problem is simply that if I click the radio button, then enter data into the TextBox (immediately - in less than 2 seconds), when the radio button returns, it deletes the data. This is annoying. Is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this is to remove `AutoPostBack=true` on the `RadioButtonList` control.  The auto-postback option immediately initiates an HTTP post back to the server, so anything typed after then is going to be lost.

Other options:

- Implement a client-side `onclick` handler, and *disable* the text while the post-back processes (ie, make it clear to the user that they can't type anything, aka the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).
- Implement the change logic completely on the client side using Javascript
- Use the ASP.Net AJAX [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) to do the postback asynchronously (this would not require a full postback to the server, so would allow you to keep typing).

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `EnableViewState="false"` on your control who lose data, and let default value of ViewState (true) on control.